# CSS align list item to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align items in a list to the right and have their width adjust to the content's length, but nothing seems to be working.

Here's my code:

```css
.messages {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 0 50px 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.messages .sent {
  background: white;
  color: #424242;
}
.messages .received {
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}
.messages .sent,
.messages .received {
  padding: 5px 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  max-width: 80%;
}
.messages * .message {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.messages .sent .message .p {
  text-align: left;
}
.messages * .message p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="messages">

  <li class="sent">
    <div class="message">
      <p>Hey</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="received">
    <div class="message">
      <p>Hey man!</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="sent">
    <div class="message">
      <p>What's up?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="message">
      <p>How are ya?</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="received">
    <div class="message">
      <p>Not bad</p>
    </div>

    <div class="message">
      <p>Not bad at all</p>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

And here is what the page looks like using that code:

[image: Current]

But here is a quickly thrown together example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Goal]

I've tried adding `display: inline-block;` under the `.messages * .message` selector and `text-align: right;` under `.messages .sent`, which instead just screwed up the entire page design.

I've been attempting to achieve what I have posted above for longer than I'm willing to admit, but nothing I do seems to work. How do I go about aligning certain items to the right in a list while keeping others aligned to the left?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your html code as well

Answer (score 2):

The container containing the text (with the background color) should be displayed inline-block, and the next containing element should align left or right.

https://jsfiddle.net/1zryafq4/1/

In short:

```
.messages .message {
   display:block;
}

.messages .message p{
   display:inline-block;
}

.messages .sent{
  text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems you are having with the text-alignment can be solved by removing the existing text-alignments in `.messages .sent .message .p` and `.messages * .message .p`, and replacing it with:

```
.messages .received {
    text-align: left;
    clear: both;
}

.messages .sent {
    width: 20%;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
```

Note that you need to float right on messages sent, and `clear: both` on both the sent and received messages. The background colours need to be moved into `messages .received .message` and `messages .sent .message`, which need their own widths:

```
.messages .received .message {
    width: 40%;
    background: dodgerblue;
}

.messages .sent .message {
    background: white;
    color: #424242;
}
```

Padding should also be updated, by moving it from `.messages .sent,
.messages .received` to `.messages * .message p`. I've compiled all of this for you in a new fiddle, so you don't have to worry too much about making these changes ;)

Updated fiddle, matching design request:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lbyyk5d7/6/

Answer (score 0):

hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
.messages {
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 50px 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #efeeec;
}

.messages .sent {
  text-align:right;
}

.messages .sent p {
    background: white;
    color: #424242;
}

.messages .received p {
    background: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
}

.messages .sent p,
.messages .received p{
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 5px 8px;
        margin: 0px;
}

.messages .message {
   display:block;
}

.messages .sent .message .p {
    text-align: left;
    display:inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="messages">

  <li class="sent">
    <div class="message">
      <p>Hey</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="received">
    <div class="message">
      <p>Hey man!</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="sent">
    <div class="message">
      <p>What's up?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="message">
      <p>How are ya?</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="received">
    <div class="message">
      <p>Not bad</p>
    </div>

    <div class="message">
      <p>Not bad at all</p>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```